# Calculate font size based on image resolution and user size inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, fonts, resize

I have a project and a problem with font scaling based on canvas.js.

The Project Detail:

- based on node.js
- use vue.js / javascript
- convas for vue

Problem:

I took a project from a former employee at work. 
The user has the option of uploading an image and this displayed on canvas as a background (its a wood product). Than he can upload images or texts and place it on them. When the user upload the product Image he can specify the height and width from it as a value (cm).

Next he can place a text element (canvas) on it and set the font size (in "pt"). The Problem is i must scale the font relative to the Produkt size from the User Input (24cm x 21cm) on the background of the product.

So have the follow values:

- background image with a resolution: 1200x950px
- product Size: 24x21cm
- font size for selection: 14, 16, .. (in pt) - think i must set the values for canvas in px but this can i calculate.

How can I scale the font relative to the values that as soon as the product is actually engraved has the correct font size and is also displayed correctly in canvas?

My former employee have leave follow calculation in project (font-size in mm):

**let fontFactor** = (height of image [950px] * 10) / height of produkt [21cm] * 100

**let fontSize (in mm)** = fontValue [16,18..] * fontFactor

Answer (score 0):

### Linear scale

It is straight forward to scale to match a given dimension as long as you establish the relationship between pixels and the scale you are working in.

For example the image size and the representative physical size can be expressed as

```
const imageSize = {
    cm: {width: 24, height: 21},
    px: {width: 1200, height: 950},
    cm2px: {width: 1200 / 24, height: 950 / 21},
    px2cm: {width: 24 / 1200, height: 21 / 950},
};
```

Giving the size of the canvas and the physical, and the conversion scales between them.

With that and knowing the scale relationship between "Points" and "cm" as 1pt = 0.0353 you can scale canvas text to match the points size in the cm scale of the canvas.

To scale and render from "px" to "point" with the above info

```
    const pt2cm = 0.0353;
    const textPointSize = 38;

    ctx.font = textPointSize + "px arial"; // In px (pixels)

    const xScale = pt2cm * imageSize.cm2px.width;
    const yScale = pt2cm * imageSize.cm2px.height;
    ctx.setTransform(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, 100, 100);

    ctx.fillText("38pt text", 0, 0);
```

### Example

The example creates a canvas and draws a cm grid. Then draws the font at various pt sizes on the canvas.

The function `drawText`  takes the font size in points, and the text position in cm

The 38pt text is approx 13mm tall in the scale of the canvas image using a point size of 0.0352778cm

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const imageSize = {
    cm: {width: 24, height: 21},
    px: {width: 1200, height: 950},
    cm2px: {width: 1200 / 24, height: 950 / 21},
    px2cm: {width: 24 / 1200, height: 21 / 950},
};
const pt2cm = 0.0352778;

canvas.width = imageSize.px.width;
canvas.height = imageSize.px.height;
drawGrid();

for (let i = 10; i < 40; i += 4) {
    drawText("Test text "+i+"pt", i, 3, 1 + (i - 10) / 2);
}

function drawText(text, sizePt, xCm, yCm) {
    const x = imageSize.cm2px.width * xCm;
    const y = imageSize.cm2px.height * yCm;
    ctx.font = sizePt+"px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top"
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    const xs = pt2cm * imageSize.cm2px.width;
    const ys = pt2cm * imageSize.cm2px.height;
    ctx.setTransform(xs, 0, 0, ys, x, y);
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}














// Draws a grid
function drawGrid() {
    const w = imageSize.px.width;
    const h = imageSize.px.height;
    const sx = imageSize.cm2px.width;
    const sy = imageSize.cm2px.height;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#aaa";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(imageSize.cm.height, imageSize.cm.width) * 5; i += 1) {
        if (i % 5) {
            ctx.rect(0, i * sy / 5 | 0, w, 1);
            ctx.rect(i * sx / 5 | 0, 0, 1, h);
        }
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(imageSize.cm.height, imageSize.cm.width); i += 1) {
        ctx.rect(0, i * sy | 0, w, 1);
        ctx.rect(i * sx | 0, 0, 1, h);
    }    
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.font = "12px arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeText("cm", 12, 10);
    ctx.fillText("cm", 12, 10);
    for(let i = 1; i < Math.max(imageSize.cm.height, imageSize.cm.width); i += 1) {
        ctx.strokeText(i, 10, i * sy);
        ctx.strokeText(i, i * sx, 10);
        ctx.fillText(i, 10, i * sy);
        ctx.fillText(i, i * sx, 10);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**Note** That the physical and pixel sizes do not match and thus the canvas scale is stretched in the y direction.

To get a square aspect you should use only one scale for both the x and y scale or change the canvas size to match the physical aspect.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for the detailed answer! Will calculate the font based on this post and give feedback!